# Can I find all the relations between two nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a group of nodes which are related in the following way:

```
        A --> B --> C --> D
```

The relation is a "connected with" relationship with some id property.
My question is: Can I write a cypher query which will show me all the id properties of each relationship from start node A to the start node D without mentioning in the query any of the nodes in between.

Thanks
Dimitris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a [variable length relationship](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#match-variable-length-relationships):

```
MATCH (a:A { name:"Some property" })-[r:connected_with*1..4]-(x)
RETURN r, x
```

Comment: Hmm. I will check this tomorrow at work. It might work!

Comment: I see now that the variable length relationship returns nodes that are around the start node (based on the number you define). What I need is to predefine somewhere the end node. And return all the relations between the start and end node.

Comment: You gave me the right direction. After all the variable length relationship is what I was looking for. My query like this:     "MATCH (x:Node)-[r:is_connected_with*]-(z:Node)  WHERE x.id='377227.4428_4277959.7572' AND z.id='373969.057300001_4274946.5112' RETURN x,r,z" works fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the followng data

```
create (a:Test {name: "A"})
create (b:Test {name: "B"})
create (c:Test {name: "C"})
create (d:Test {name: "D"})
create a-[:CONNECTED_TO]->b
create b-[:CONNECTED_TO]->c
create c-[:CONNECTED_TO]->d
return *
```

The following query will return a collection of ids for each node in the path.

```
match p=(a:Test)-[:CONNECTED_TO*3]->(d:Test)
return reduce(nodes = [],n in nodes(p) | nodes + [id(n)]) as node_id_col
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I replace the 3 with some wildcard character in case the number of the nodes between the start and end node is not fixed? Also what I need is to get the id which is stored inside each relationship not the id of each node!

Comment: you can replace the 3 with a bare asterisk (e.g. CONNECTED_TO*) or a range (e.g. CONNECTED_TO*1..5).  I would be cautious about using a bare asterisk though as it could literally bring your system to its knees depending on your data.

Answer (score 1):

Basing this off of Dave Bennett's data, the following cypher query would get the all the nodes and the relationships between then (provided they are all CONNECTED_TO) and their associated properties in a path of arbitrary length.

```
MATCH (x:Test)-[r:CONNECTED_TO*]->(z:Test)
RETURN x, r, z
```