# Retrieving a list of nodes along with a list of IDs of nodes that are directly related to them in Neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

In my database I have :User nodes, and they are related by :Friendship relationships. I want to get a structure like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "Whatever",
        email: "whatever@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 6, 7, 8, ... ]
],
[
    {
        id: 2,
        username: "Another user",
        email: "anotheruser@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 15, 16, 17, 18, ... ]
],
...
```

...where the numbers are the IDs of the nodes that the node is directly related to with a :Friendship relationship.

This answer has some queries that *almost* do the work:

[Can I find all the relations between two nodes in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848429/can-i-find-all-the-relations-between-two-nodes-in-neo4j)

But the closest one I came up with was:

```
match p=(a:User)-[:Friendship]->(d:User)
return d, reduce(nodes = [],n in nodes(p) | nodes + [id(n)]) as node_id_col
```

...which returns this structure:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "Whatever",
        email: "whatever@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 1, 6 ]
],
[
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "Whatever",
        email: "whatever@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 1, 7 ]
],
[
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "Whatever",
        email: "whatever@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 1, 8 ]
],
[
    {
        id: 2,
        username: "Another user",
        email: "anotheruser@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 2, 15 ]
],
[
    {
        id: 2,
        username: "Another user",
        email: "anotheruser@test.com"
        ...
    },
    [ 2, 16 ]
],
...
```

That is not good, because it is returning a lot of redundant data.

So what would be the proper Cypher query for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating things OR I am not properly understanding the problem. Does something like this work for you?

```
match (a:User)-[:Friendship]->(d:User)
return a, collect(id(d))
```